# cannot add unallocated space to extended partition using gparted

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, gparted

Okay, I installed Ubuntu a while back and realized I needed more storage space so I shrunk the size of my Windows partition but I am unable to expand the Ubuntu partition.  I've read several similar questions and tried different things but I simply add to the Linux partition.  As it is right now, I can't move the extended partition (sd3) at all.

I've attached a screen shot here.  My apologies for the crappy quality...I could not figure out for the life of me how to save the screen shot from the live gparted CD :([image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you:

1. Move sda2 to the right (maybe shrink it a bit too)
2. Increase the size of sda3 to fill the space
3. Move sda6 all the way to the right
4. Increase the size of sda5

Are you saying it won't let you do that?

Make sure you have none of those partitions mounted too. :)